# Linux graphical application for filling up a database

Tags: linux, database, gui

I know I could write a proper database application but that would be an overkill for this.

I would like to process the e-mails in a mailing list to have a big picture on what are the main problems users face when use the software in question.

I would like to have an easy to use interface so that I can label entries on different categories, preferably choosing these labels from a drop-down menu.

What would you recommend for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mozilla Thunderbird** do all tasks you requested. There is a "tag" action available on a context menu, and from the top menu too. You can define personal tags, and numeric shortcuts will be attached to them (only numbers from 1 to 9, as i can see).

You can move to folders, or do some other kind of administration you prefer to do the task you describe. You can obviously pre filter based on keywords, filtering options are very powerful too, and can automatize the problem you posted to some extent.

Comment: Can I somehow download the mails from a pipermail archive?

Comment: Apparently folders on thunderbird are stored on pipermail format. See [here](http://johnpoelstra.com/importing-mailing-list-archives-to-thunderbird/) for a brief tutorial on how to use a pipermail file on thunderbird (never tested it, but appears to be safe)

Comment: Thanks. I have found several non-working scripts, but in one of them I got well-configured wget command that did the trick, with a concatenation of the individual text files. Now I have the whole archive in a local folder